# Delete File Even A Fatal Error

Tags: php

I am trying to create an online php editor .Alternative to eval , i am doing it as

> 1. Get the codes by form post (having an iframe as target) request and save it in a temp file
> 2. including that temp file ,so codes gets executed
> 3. deleting that temp file

**CODE**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['winCode']))
{
  $data=$_POST['winCode'];
  $_SESSION['data']=$data; 
  // creating a $_SESSION['data'] ,so that
  // user can maximize the resultant iframe
}
file_put_contents(session_id()."_runphp.php",$_SESSION['data']);
include(session_id()."_runphp.php");//generate output
unlink(session_id()."_runphp.php");//delete temp file
?>
```

This is working well , but when a user generates error by his codes ..unlink doesn't work .. *How can i set unlink to run even a fatal error occurs.*

Comment: `include(session_id()."_runphp.php")` .... seriously??? You've got a unique PHP file for every user session? WTF? I think you need to seriously rethink your application design.

Comment: whats the problem ?? Can u give an alternative.. @Simba

Comment: That single line of code implies a whole bunch of security flaws in your system. There's a high likelihood that your system is vulnerable to code injection attacks. There's insufficient code here for me to see enough of what you're doing to suggest alternative solutions, but I suggest reading up a few good security-related articles on the web.

Comment: @Simba ,thanks for your point .. but this is a project for an institution where student may run small php programs quickly ..As far as issues of security dangerous functions are already disabled as well .

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I'll leave it at that. Just as long as you're aware that this is highly risky functionality, even when "dangerous functions are disabled". There is a lot of risk here, and a developer writing this kind of code needs to be certain that their code is bulletproof.

Answer (score 1):

Use `register_shutdown_function`.

Follow the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

---

```
register_shutdown_function( "shutdown_handler" );

function shutdown_handler() {
  // delete file here
}
```

---

***Note: This is not a good practice to execute the user entered code as it is. This system to open to Cross Site Scripting Attacks.***

Comment: thanks , but unlink function generating a warning for path :`No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\oEditor\result.php on line 15`

Comment: @RohitKumar - so check whether it exists before trying to unlink it. (But if you're getting that error there, then surely the `include()` will also be failing?)

Comment: @Simba , include() is working but callback to unlink file generating warning ,and file is still not deleted

Comment: @RohitKumar - check file permissions. You may not have permissions to delete the file.

Comment: Its must not be an issue , since file was deleted when no fatal error occurs in orignal problem .. even i have checked the file permission ,its ok

Comment: Okay. Try using absolute path.

Comment: Yeah , with absolute path it is working now .. but when an error is there file permissions warning gets triggered .. looks amazing to me